# Angular interface names mess

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, namespaces

I work with an API which has different fields for the same entity regarding the context. For example if I get list of entities I receive only half of the fields and when I get one specific entity by id I get it full. Also, when I need to send this entity to the server (create a new one) I need to send another set of fields.

It's unsuitable to use optional `?` sign in interface for fields because for  "getList" these fields are never going to come and therefore I shouldn't mislead with interface and so forth with other cases.

In result I have about 3-4 interfaces (1st for save, 2nd for getList, 3rd for getById, 4th for this entity as part of another entity and so forth) for the same Entity. According to Angular's tslint rules it's not suitable to use Namespaces (what I was thinking of using).

**How do I structure all my interfaces in a natural for understanding and good for maintenance way?**

For now I can think of `BaseEntityInterface` which may be the core with all common always present fields.

Then `ListEntityInterface extends BaseEntityInterface` which would have additional properties and so forth. However, this leads to non-intuitive long names.

For those who want to say that it's not recommended to use `interface` suffix or `I` prefix I want to mention that this is a step because of classes that may be present for these entities (they have own methods which are used only in its very own context and when entities are passed to some method they are usually not instance of this class).

---

### Update #1

For example we have an Employee entity.

Base interface (the one that we may reuse in all interfaces) would look like

```
export interface BaseEmployeeInterface {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender: string;
}
```

Now when one tries to getEmployee(id)

```
export interface GetEmployeeResponse extends BaseEmployeeInterface {
  startDate: string;
  status: string;
  salary: number;
  extra: ExtraDataFull; // some large object
}
```

However, if one accesses getEmployeeList they receive `GetEmployeeListResponse[]`

```
export interface GetEmployeeListResponse extends GetEmployeeResponse {
  extra: ExtraDataShort; // some essential parts of a large object data
  // and some other props
}
```

Now, if one accesses getGuestList they receive `GetGuestList[]`

```
export interface GetGuestList {
  name: string;
  items: ItemList[];
  ref: Omit<GetEmployeeListResponse, ...>; // All but some props
}
```

And now there is at least 4 variants of Employee entity data received and it's not limited by this numer. If I need to declare an interface for creating Eployee entity there would be the 5th case of the type.

Here when I use `ref: Omit<GetEmployeeListResponse, ...>` I need to remember this type declaration or create another type to reuse this interface.

Also, I want to mention that this case is very simplified since in my application the interface is about 5 times larger.

P.S. There is at least two other entity endpoints which include some parts of Employee entity data and this is 4 more (for each endpoint 1 for list and 1 for get*(id))

Comment: Consider using some utility types. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html. Pick | Partial | Omit spring to mind for your use case. If you can give some examples of the interfaces could try give a more detailed suggestion

Comment: @c_ogoo the thing you've suggested is a reverse to what I'm doing. But still if I want to reuse these interfaces elsewhere I have to declare them and therefore "pollute" global interfaces

Comment: I'm not sure im following, are you able to share some of the interface definitions?

Comment: @c_ogoo I'll share later

Comment: @c_ogoo updated the question